# Is there a way to append files to the already existing files list? javascript file api

Tags: javascript, flash, html, file-upload, upload

Is there a way to append files to the already existing files list?

```
function file_select_handler(e){   
    file_drag_hover(e);  

    var new_files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    //something like:
    files.append(new_files);

    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {  
        parse_file(f); 
    }  
}
```

EDIT// I have now tried this:

```
function file_select_handler(e){   
file_drag_hover(e);    

    var new_files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    files_collect.push(new_files);

    for (a in files_collect) {    
        for (b in files_collect[a]) {  
            parse_file(files_collect[a][b]); 
        }  
    }  
}
```

//EDIT NOT ANSWER:::://

But the above seems to put a pointer into the array, so when more files are chosen, they replace the others stored in the array. CRAZY? ANY help?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into doing this with Flash/Java. There's several reasons this cannot be achieved with JS: security concerns, the fact 'file' input types only allow selection of file(s) (not folder(s)).

Comment: you can select multiple files using javascript and html5. Alas i don't think it allows categorisation (ie folders).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that it was possible. More and more about html 5 keeps coming out that changes the game we've all been playing for so long.

Comment: You can't select folders, only files, with Flash (it is possible in AIR apps, but not in Flash Player in a web browser).